# ionic cap run android -l --external command throws the following: [ERROR] No devices or emulators found

Tags: ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools, livereload

I'm following the First Ionic App with React tutorial [Ionic Tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app)

I'm having a problem in the live reload section of the tutorial [Live reload section of the tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app/live-reload)
when I try to run the ionic cap run android -l --external command it throws the following error: [ERROR] No devices or emulators found.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUlUF.png)

I already have installed the following SDK plataforms
[Plataforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFksf.png)

and tools
[Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ3XD.png)

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64-bits

Thanks in advance

I've followed the tutorial step by step and the Live Reload server should start up, and the native IDE of choice should open if not opened already.

Comment: what is giving :  adb devices on terminal ?

Comment: Hi, it gives:

`09:10:40 gabriel@ThinkPad-T460 photo-gallery ±|master ✗|→ adb devices 
List of devices attached
R9TMB0BNP4J device
`

The device also appears on android studio

[Device in android studio](https://imgur.com/Ktf9cYN)

Comment: Ok. So if adb can detect thats ok. Close and open again vscode or whatever editor you use.
Have you done : 

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/home/myhome/Android/Sdk"
export ANDROID_HOME="/myhome/myhome/Android/Sdk"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/variables
Check the threat
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-capacitor-run-android-list-cant-find-devices/210592/31

Comment: Hi stefani, thanks a lot for your help, the problem is already solved, the only little 'inconvenience' is that I changed the npm global default directory so I have to change the source back and forth, I don't know if there is a more elegant way to manage the environments, but so far it is working fine, thanks again.

Comment: Welcome. Yu ca just uninstall and reinstall again nodejs and npm or just edit env variables.  Im having this C:\Users\stefani-toto\AppData\Roaming\npm